# How do I enumerate all properties in an object and obtain their values?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to enumerate all properties: private, protected, public etc. I wish to use the built in facilities and not use any third party code.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you working with? Enhanced RTTI is available only since Delphi 2010. Older versions won't be able to achieve this: only published properties can be listed.

Comment: You are asking about getting the values of all properties. The new RTTI, available in Delphi XE2, is able to do this. The link I posted as duplicate was some reference about using RTTI, in general. There was no indication of the Delphi version you were using. Since you edited your question, I deleted my duplicate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , Thanks for modifying my questions nicely.

Comment: The cardinal question of course being "WHY?!?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Extended RTTI like this (when I tested the code in XE I got exception on ComObject property, so I inserted try - except block):

```
uses RTTI;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  C: TRttiContext;
  T: TRttiType;
  F: TRttiField;
  P: TRttiProperty;

  S: string;

begin
  T:= C.GetType(TButton);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('---- Fields -----');
  for F in T.GetFields do begin
    S:= F.ToString + ' : ' + F.GetValue(Button1).ToString;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
  end;

  Memo1.Lines.Add('---- Properties -----');
  for P in T.GetProperties do begin
    try
      S:= P.ToString;
      S:= S + ' : ' + P.GetValue(Button1).ToString;
      Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    except
      ShowMessage(S);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 9):

Serg's answer is good but it is better to avoid exceptions by skipping some types:

```
uses
  Rtti, TypInfo;

procedure TForm4.GetObjectProperties(AObject: TObject; AList: TStrings);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  rType: TRttiType;
  rProp: TRttiProperty;
  AValue: TValue;
  sVal: string;
const
  SKIP_PROP_TYPES = [tkUnknown, tkInterface];
begin
  if not Assigned(AObject) and not Assigned(AList) then
    Exit;

  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  rType := ctx.GetType(AObject.ClassInfo);
  for rProp in rType.GetProperties do
  begin
    if (rProp.IsReadable) and not (rProp.PropertyType.TypeKind in SKIP_PROP_TYPES) then
    begin
      AValue := rProp.GetValue(AObject);
      if AValue.IsEmpty then
      begin
        sVal := 'nil';
      end
      else
      begin
        if AValue.Kind in [tkUString, tkString, tkWString, tkChar, tkWChar] then
          sVal := QuotedStr(AValue.ToString)
        else
          sVal := AValue.ToString;
      end;

      AList.Add(rProp.Name + '=' + sVal);
    end;

  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an excellent starting point using advanced capabilities of recent Delphi version:

- [Rtti Explorer Lite](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/fun-with-delphi-rtti-rtti-explorer-lite/) by [RRUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz).

The following link rather targets early version (from D5 on). Based on the unit TypInfo.pas, it's limited but still instructive:

- [RTTI Explorer v.1.1](http://www.torry.net/vcl/vcltools/objectinspectors/RTTI_Explorer.zip) by [Niek Sluyter](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=5982).